# Ionic 4 - error on ionic cordova android build "Source and destination must not be same"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I got this error after changing the package name and delete some folder in npm folder , how ever i have revert it back to it's original name but the error still exists

[image: The error]

Comment: I answered the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127362/fs-extra-source-and-destination-must-not-be-the-same-cordova/55134598#55134598. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option would be to remove the platform and re-add it with the following commands:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Awesome - glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

At first, manually remove this:

`node_modules` folder

`package-lock.json` file

`platform > android` folder

[image]

[image]

then use this commend:

```
1 => npm rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
2 => npm cache clear --force
3 => ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0
4 => ionic cordova prepare android
5 => ionic cordova run android
```